# Change "theme" of upgraded WSS2.0 site to default SPF 2013 (Upgrade Site Collection)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Total N00b in Sharepoint land here, pls forgive my ignorance, trying to drink as fast as I can from the firehose :)

I was tasked with upgrading a WSS 2.0 site to SPF 2013 (yes, it can be done; no, you don't want to do it...) I have one content db with one web application, that contains two site collections (one is at the base "/" URL and is unused, and the one I'm concerned with is located at "/sites/management".) After the upgrade, both sites has a SPF 2010-looking theme (not sure of my term usage here, so hopefully I don't confuse anyone...) On the site at "/", there was a link at the top in a pinkish field that said "Experience all that SharePoint 15 has to offer. Start now or Remind me later", which took me to an upgrade screen. I did go ahead and do the upgrade, and now that site looks like the default SPF 2013 sites I see in the books and documentation I've been reading (the one with the blue block at the upper left with the SharePoint logo.). However, it did NOT update the site look at "/sites/management". There is no link to upgrade the site at the top of that page as there was on the "/" site. How can I change the "theme" of this site to be the default SPF 2013 one?

Comment: For some odd reason, while I did not get the top pink block "Experience all that SharePoint 15 has to offer" on the "/sites/management" site collection, my boss (who is also designated as a SharePoint admin) did, and we were able to use it to upgrade the site. Is there any other way to trigger the upgrade for a certain site collection?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You have to be set as a SharePoint "Site collection administrator" for the site collection in question to be able to upgrade the site to v15.

To do this in SPF 2013:

1. Go to SharePoint Central Administration website
2. Click on "Application Management" on the left nav bar
3. Under the "Site Collections" subsection, click the link for "Change site collection administrators"
4. Ensure that the site collection you want to operate on is showing by the "Site Collection" label. If not, click on the link of the site that is showing, select "Change Site Collection", and choose the correct site from the resulting list, then click "OK".
5. Set the Primary and Secondary Site Collection Administrators as appropriate.Then click the "OK" button to save.

You should then be able to see the pinkish box offering you the chance to upgrade the site when you browse to the site.